# Spring Cloud Contract with FHIR HAPI

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract, hapi-fhir

I need to introduce Spring Cloud Contract to mock an FHIR HAPI.

Unfortunately I didn't found any documentation about such a particular integration case.

Can someone tell me:

- Spring Cloud Contract is able to manage FHIR HAPI
- where I can find some documentation ?

I tried to implement the FHIR case as the standard one, by following this example:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-contract
but it fails in server side stub creation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My question is more theoretical: I would know if is it possible to use Spring Cloud Contract with FHIR HAPI lib.